# sqlite find out the date difference

Tags: sqlite

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_zone` (
    `item`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `zone`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `action_date`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `price` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `days_price_established`    INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO `item_zone` VALUES (50374500, 1, 1512248400, 5, 10);
INSERT INTO `item_zone` VALUES (50374500, 1, 1513112400, 9, 1);
INSERT INTO `item_zone` VALUES (50374500, 1, 1513198800, 8, null);
```

The table has no some primary key, but i think it's possible to use oid. 
In action_date it stores UNIX-like data and in days_price_established it stores how much days left from last price changing (action_data(n) - action_data(n-1). I need to show the days_price_estableshed, but i dunno how to property do math with dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the date of price modification date:

```
select strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(action_date-(86400*days_price_established), 'unixepoch')) from item_zone;
```

To show the date of last price modification:

```
select strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(action_date-(86400*days_price_established), 'unixepoch')) from item_zone;
```

To calculate days_price_established

```
select item,action_date,round((iz1.action_date-(SELECT iz2.action_date FROM item_zone iz2 WHERE iz2.oid<iz1.oid AND iz2.item=iz1.item ORDER by iz2.oid DESC limit 1))/86400) from item_zone iz1 order by iz1.oid;
```

To update days_price_established inside table if its empty

```
update item_zone set days_price_established=(select round((iz1.action_date-(SELECT iz2.action_date FROM item_zone iz2 WHERE iz2.oid<iz1.oid AND iz2.item=iz1.item ORDER by iz2.oid DESC limit 1))/86400) from item_zone iz1 WHERE iz1.oid=item_zone.oid) WHERE days_price_established IS NULL;
```

Comment: last query was pretty similar with that's i need, so i solve it with this, thanks a lot. Its's would work only in sqlite this way? And can i ask you about i more similar table or i just need to start new ask?

Comment: The query would look similar on postgresql, just instead strftime You should use to_char('YYYY-MM-DD' ... . Just ask here if you need clarification.

Comment: Can i somehow Write an insert with pure SQL which will create the price for the first day of each month for item “050374500” in the zone 1 for the some period 
 (for example 01.05.2017 – 01.03.2018) ?

Comment: Where should the price come from? Should be calculated or You want to add it manually?

Comment: in this case prise fixed, for example would be 5, but if woudnt hard for you can you write query when the first prise like 5 and each month it should multiply for 1.2 (in this case, if needed you can add some collums like price mult or something, thats just for up my understanding of sql).